# A good reference for uniformization theorem for compact and non-compact Riemann surface

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for a good reference for the uniformization theorem for Riemann surfaces, which states that each simply connected Riemannian surface is conformally equivalent to the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, the Riemann sphere $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ or the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$.

I know one proof from Ahlfors book, where the Perron's method was used. However, the proof is quite involved in constructing the analytic/(sub)harmonic functions. I followed the book by Taylor, where he use solvability of certain elliptic pde for the curvature equation. However, the proof only works for compact Riemann spheres. I wonder whether there is a better reference now.

I am aware of the following related question 
[Uniformization theorem for Riemann surfaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10516/uniformization-theorem-for-riemann-surfaces)
Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: dror varolin's book has some weird applications of uniformization theorem but i don't remember if it has a proof

Comment: To Koushik: do you mean in his book, there is a nice proof of the uniformization theorem? If so, could you please give me more information on the book, such as authors, name of the book, publication year...

Comment: Did you try Markushevich, Theory of functions of a complex variable? There you can find a proof of the theorem that any open simply connected subset of $P^1(C)$ whose complement has at least two points is biholomorphic to the disc (at least the proof was there in the italian version).

Comment: To Tommasco: Thanks very much. I haven't check the book you mentioned. I really want to find a relatively accessible proof for a presentation.

Comment: @Changyu Guo: Following Koushik comment, the reference is: "Riemann Surfaces by Way of Complex Analytic Geometry" by Dror Varolin. Graduate Texts in Mathematics Vol. 125, American Mathematical Society, 2011. The Uniformization Theorem is proved in Chapter 10: the statement is on p. 168, the proof in p. 174--175, and in pages  168--175 the author discusses some implications of the theorem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good reference in English is Hubbard, Teichmuller theory, Matrix editions, Ithaca, NY, 2006, MR2245223. There is a very good reference in French,
H. P. de Saint Gervais, Uniformisation des surfaces de Riemann, ENS Editions, 2010.
It is a whole book dedicated to the Uniformisation theory and its history.

A short easily readable exposition in English is Abikoff, The uniformization theorem.
Amer. Math. Monthly 88 (1981), no. 8, 574–592.

A recently published graduate CV textbook which contains a proof is
D. Marshall, Complex Analysis.